# How to fully reset network adapter?

Tags: windows, networking

If the client computer has no connectivity to the Internet or Windows network domain, what are the commands to fully reset the network adapter and related cache, services, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the client is running recent version of Windows... open an elevated command prompt and try some of these. I usually never need to go past the first four ipconfig commands.

**flush and register dns, release and renew ip**

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /registerdns
```

**flush arp cache**

```
netsh interface ip delete arpcache
```

**get nic list and index**

```
wmic nic get name, index
```

**disable nic with index number (4 as example)**

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=4 call disable
```

**enable nic with index (4 as example)**

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=4 call enable
```

**example stop and start Windows service: "DNS Client"**

```
net stop "DNS Client"
net start "DNS Client"
```

Admittedly, when it comes to the list of services, I'm not sure which ones you'll need to look into but I give one example of how to stop and start them.